# writing htaccess rules for redirection

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website, lets say `www.domain.com`

and my current blog is at `www.domain.com/blog/`

so my URLs are like `www.domain.com/blog/recent-post/`

now Im having a new wordpress installation to handle blog, and pointed a subdomian to it, so the blog now is `blog.domain.com`

I have lot of seo work dne for`www.domain.com/blog/` I dont want to miss that, and I want to redirect users visiting `www.domain.com/blog/` to `www.blog.domain.com/`
and `www.domain.com/blog/any-url/`  to `www.blog.domain.com/any-url/`

can some one help in writing redirection rule for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change `domain.com/blog` to `blog.domain.com`?

This isn't good for SEO, since the links do not have the same value for a directory that for a subdomain.

Better to have the blog in a folder that subdomain, since the authority will always go to main domain (`domain.com`).

Answer (score 0):

If in spite of @Cailbuig's advice you still want to do this, what you'd need is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?^ http://blog.domain.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

Start with R=302 and then when it works change to R=301. 301 reponses are cached by browsers, so they are hard to test.